# Анимированный gif файл с тегом video

Tags: html, css

?Всем привет. Опыта маловато, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Есть у меня два анимированных файла в формате gif файл первый [Левый](https://habrastorage.org/webt/q2/pg/ff/q2pgffqkmgkcpwwbify5cd6mvoq.gif)

файл второй [Правый](https://habrastorage.org/webt/s_/yk/eo/s_ykeof0f15-dy2gci5evfp-oeo.gif)

Необходимо чтобы эти файлы выводились по очереди на экран через определенные промежутки времени.
Примерно так: первый фал через 2 сек. и исчез с экрана, второй файл через 15 сек. и тоже исчез, и так далее 9 раз ( всего показов первого файла 5 раз, второго 4 раза, показ файлов в разных местах страницы). Файлы имеют по 36 кадров, длительность кадров 0,01 сек., в параметрах повторов поставлено однократно. Почему описываю так подробно? Пробовал сделать всё это с дивом
image, так как я хотел у меня не получилось. Если есть вариант осуществления такой анимации, жду варианты решения. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть 2 файла, указаны по ссылкам выше, Надо чтобы эти два файла поочередно выводились на экран с разными промежутками времени, в разных местах (с разными координатами отображения на странице).